# how to delete "default-string" name@name-Default-string

Tags: command-line, 18.04

Recently started using Ubuntu, just wondering how to change my computer name.

as when i made my account, it says at the end of it "default-string"

name@name-Default-string

Answer (score 1):

You can change your computer name by editing `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` files with root permission.

Don't forget to restart your hostname service by running `sudo service hostname restart`.