# Why does default-string appear after hostname in etc/hosts?

Tags: root, hostname, etc

Referencing: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208749/how-to-delete-default-string-namename-default-string)

The author is asking how to change `hostname` when it includes the appendage ´default-string´,

If `root` is required to change the file in the path `etc/hosts` should this be changed?
This is my configuration.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       myhostname-Default-string

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

As my question asks, why am I seeing ´default-string´?

Also, is this standard formatting for hostname in the directory mentioned above?

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880270/what-are-the-default-settings-for-etc-hosts-and-etc-hostname) appears to say this is not the case.

Therefore, is it safe to use `root` to change?

By the way. I have **not** changed my hostname, ever.

Ubuntu 20.04.2LTS

Comment: Maybe it's because you didn't enter a hostname during installation - just a guess. But yes, you can easily change your hostname here and in the file `etc/hostname`.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense now. I didn´t enter one during installation, As far as I remember. I get ´sudo: unable to resolve host *****: Temporary failure in name resolution¨ when running sudo apt update, for example. But then on entering password commands seem to work okay.